# Possible to alert server to iphone settings change?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm working on giving our users context-specific PUSH notification settings, similar to what Facebook has in their settings menu.

As far as I can tell though, there's no way to actually notify our server of these changes until the user actually launches the app.

Is this correct?  Is there any mechanism provided for immediately alerting our servers to a settings change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct: you can't detect changes made in the settings app until the next time your app launches.

The closest option to what you're describing would be to put the settings in your app somewhere and notify the server from there.